# HTML form tag action attribute is blank but the submit button still work?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit-button

It's a XSS Game web to do XSS attack. And about the level 1, I have a doubt about how the form is submitted, the action is blank, so what make the submit button work?
http://www.xssgame.com/f/m4KKGHi2rVUN/?
it's html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: #ffffff;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="/static/js/js_frame.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
      <img src="/static/img/foogle.png">
      <br>
      <form action="" method="GET">
        <input id="demo2-query" name="query" value="Enter query here..."
          onfocus="this.value=''">
        <input id="demo2-button" type="submit" value="Search">
      </form>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the js_frame.js file is:

```
top.postMessage({url:window.location.toString()},"*");var originalAlert=window.alert;
window.alert=function(b){function a(){document.getElementById("next_level")?originalAlert("Congratulations, you executed an alert:\n\n"+b+"\n\nYou can now advance to the next level."):originalAlert("You executed an alert, but the server side validation of your solution failed. It probably means that your solution requires user interaction, or is not generic enough to work for a different user. Please try to make it work without user interaction and generic enough so that it works for any user.")}console.log("solved");
top.postMessage("success","*");"onvalidationready"in window?window.onvalidationready=a:setTimeout(a,0)};
```

add: I see the html code don't include code that can receive the submit, or it's because chrome console's Sources won't show all code?

Comment: Your button working because of it is inside of `form`. And by the way, if `<form action="">` is empty, it meaning data will send to current file.

Comment: Just switch from submit, to other type

Answer (score 1):

Action attribute with blank will use current page as target. This works that way in all browsers despite [HTML 4 specification saying](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-action) action other than URL is undefined.

With HTML5, it is actually written that way also in the specification.

Answer (score 1):

When the action attribute of form is left blank, then the form is submitted to the same page when the submit button is clicked. If you don't want your form to be submitted when the submit button is clicked..

just replace your form tag with this :

```
<form action="" onsubmit="return false" method="GET">
```

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of form submit is that the content is sent to action url file on the server for processing. If no action is specified or action is kept blank, browser assume that the current file (containing the html form) is also the processing file. Therefore the request is made for current page Url as action.

If you donot need this behavior, I suggest you to use `<input type="button" />` or simple `button` tag in you page.